# Missing CreateChildContainer in Unity 5.9.x

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

There used to be a method `UnityContainer.CreateChildContainer()` in Unity IoC version 5.8.x. However it has dissipated since version 5.9.x. Does it mean that whole child container feature was removed? Is there any other way how to achieve that?

Comment: How did you conclude that there is no `CreateChildContainer`?

Comment: This code does not work since 5.9.0: `var container = new UnityContainer(); var child = container.CreateChildContainer();`

Comment: Could you try `IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer(); var child = container.CreateChildContainer();` instead of using `var`?

Comment: Yes, this works, because CreateChildContainer is now (since 5.9.0) explicit implementation of IUnityContainer in UnityContainer class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do suppose that you tried to use `var` syntactic sugar when defining `UnityContainer`. Since version 5.9.0 `IUnityContainer.CreateChildContainer` has explicit implementation within `UnityContainer`. Therefore using `var` might lead to impression that `CreateChildContainer` but also any other explicitly implemented method is not there anymore.

```
//Not possible with unity>=5.9.0, this way uc has access to class methods
var uc = new UnityContainer();
using(var child = uc.CreateChildContainer()){...}

//Possible with unity>=5.9.0, this way uc has access to interface methods
IUnityContainer uc = new UnityContainer();
using(var child = uc.CreateChildContainer()){...}
```

---

n.b. This is generally the behavior with `var` and explicitly implemented interface methods